# Boot linux live iso from multi-partitioned SD card

Tags: linux, iso, gparted, sd-card, bootable

I have a 32Gb SD card that I want to boot a linux ISO from.  I can write the image using balena, dd etc. and it works fine.

However this is a bit wasteful as the ISO is a fraction of this size.  I'd like to partition the SD card and have it remain bootable - so one partition contains the ISO (Joliet, I guess) and the other to be ext4 or something similar.

When I try this (using gparted and dd or disk manager) the SD won't boot.  Where am I going wrong?

Am I trying to achieve the impossible?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, you can create a 5 or 6GB FAT32 partition with boot,esp flags & then extract ISO into that partition. Then rest of SD can be anything. But your system has to be able to boot from SD card, not all systems will directly boot a SD card. Some then put SD card in a USB adapter, so seen as USB boot. I also have used grub installed to flash drive to loopmount boot many ISO on one USB  drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media ISO boot & link to examples
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: You can create a persistent live drive (of Ubuntu, Debian and some similar Linux distros) with [mkusb-dus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), and after that edit the partition table with gparted (but don't move the head end of the boot partition). During these edits you can create partitions for various tasks. (It is even possible to get an installed system alongside the persistent live system.)

Comment: It's a machine with BIOS, I think too old for UEFI (Actually an Asus EEE 900).  It has a built-in SD card reader which it will boot from quite happily - although internally the machine treats it as a USB device.

Comment: What I've tried so far:

- image the entire drive: `dd if=file.iso of=/dev/sde` (this works fine)


- partition the drive (using fdisk or gparted): dd (as above) to 1st partition and format 2nd partition as ext4 (this either never boots [black screen] or produces the error "isolinux.bin missing or corrupt")


- imaging the drive then resizing the resulting partition with gparted: gparted won't resize a partition of type ISO9600 (Joliet). tried with fdisk but it won't resize an existing partition


I may try the grub route next.

Comment: @BrongersCroste, A few years ago I 'inherited' an ASUS eeePC 900. Yes, it is rather good at booting from either the internal drive (which is quite small), a USB pendrive or an SD card. You can only use 32-bit operating systems in this computer. Which distro are you testing. If I remember correctly, I had good luck with Bionic Pup. And it can also use 'the rest of the drive' if installed in the correct way. I think you can find good advice at some Puppy forum, or at [this link](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/633850/puppy-linux-corner/) managed by Mike Walsh.

Comment: You can also use a Debian 32-bit iso file and use [mkusb-dus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to create a persistent live system, which can use the whole drive.